# Firebase VDT does not run Gherkin (Cucumber) tests

Tags: android, cucumber, firebase-test-lab

I'm running integration tests with VDT. 
I build the two APKs and then I send them following the tutorial that is referenced here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous for Bitrise.

Firebase successfully runs my non-Cucumber tests but it just ignores the Cucumber tests.

When I install the APKs on my device I see all the tests running.
I checked and the Runner in the APK is set to `MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner`.

To know the runner that is used in the androidTest apk I did this:

1. Install the APK that I'm sending to Firebase
2. Run `adb shell pm list instrumentation`

Then I see the line:
`instrumentation:my.package.name.test/.MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner (target=my.package.name)`

This is the MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner that I have integrated into the app:
https://gist.github.com/dhoskins/98afa6976c87cb20328d42065c7292ee

Do you know how I can investigate why the tests are not running? Have you had this issue too?

**EDIT**
Now I know that I can make it working turning the Orchestrator off. Is there a way to run Cucumber test using the Orchestrator?

When the Orchestrator is on, this is the result of the tests:

> INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream= no
>   tests found: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test= INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=no tests
>   found INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1 INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   Error in no tests found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid
>   name: no tests found  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)  at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
>     at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
>     at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
>     at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
>     at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   my.package.name..app4test.test.MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner.onStart(MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner.kt:25)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)

Comment: What I've found now is that the tests run if I disable the Orchestrator. Is it possible to run Cucumber tests with the Orchestrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for the Orchestrator seems to be added for android cucumber version [4.2.4](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-android/blob/1c9dc8f23c4b12f964a27cf3c333167be0f7c73c/cucumber-android/src/main/java/cucumber/api/android/CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner.java#L8). You can try to integrate `CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner` from the library instead of `MultiDexCucumberJUnitRunner` from the gist.

In case your project is not AndroidX yet, change `androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` to `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` they should have the same implementation.

Comment: I am trying to use the cucumber-android `4.2.4`. When I upload my app to FTL the first test runs fine but then the instrumentation hangs itself until test time is expired. I cannot see any crashes from logcat. There is no difference between running with Orchestrator or not. @65536 I would suggest to try the latest version.